# Bash- Converting a variable to human readable format (KB, MB, GB)

Tags: bash, unix

In my bash script, I run through a list of directories and read in the size of each directory to a variable using the du command. I also keep a running total of the total size of the directories. The only problem is that after I get the total size, it's in an unreadable format (ex. 64827120). How can I convert the variable containing this number into GBs, MBs, etc?

Comment: You should be reading the man page of every command you use so you know what its capabilities are.

Comment: If you want a slightly more general solution (e.g., raw digits on stdin, human readable stuff on stdout), I once played with ruby gems https://github.com/pjump/human_bytes .

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`numfmt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) to convert raw (decimal) numbers
to human-readable form. 
Use `--to=iec` to output [binary-prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) numbers
(i.e., K=1024, M=2<sup>20</sup>, etc.)

```
$ printf '%s %s\n' 1000000 foo 1048576 bar | numfmt --to=iec
977K foo
1.0M bar
```

and use `--to=si` to output [metric-prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) numbers
(i.e., K=1000, M=10<sup>6</sup>, etc.)

```
$ printf '%s %s\n' 1000000 foo 1048576 bar | numfmt --to=si
1.0M foo
1.1M bar
```

If you specifically want to get “MB”, “GB”, etc., use `--suffix`:

```
$ printf '%s %s\n' 1000000 foo 1048576 bar | numfmt --to=si --suffix=B
1.0MB foo
1.1MB bar
```

If your numbers are in a column other than the first
(as in [Mik R’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31569739/3960947#64674033)), use `--field`:

```
$ printf '/home/%s %s\n' foo 1000000 bar 1048576 | numfmt --to=si --field=2
/home/foo    1.0M
/home/bar    1.1M
```

Or you can convert numbers on the command line (instead of using a pipe):

```
$ numfmt --to=si 1000000 1048576
1.0M
1.1M
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `du -h` which gives you a 'human readable' output ie KB, MB, GB, etc.

Comment: I tried doing that before, but it gave me errors when I try to add it to the running total. For example, when adding "0+4.0K", it would return "syntax error: invalid arithmetic error(error token is .0K)". I was using du -s to get just the number of bytes or whatever size it is stored as, then convert it to KB, MB at the very end.

Comment: @Swandrew, So if you had a total in _bytes_ what problem were you having converting it to your desired _value?  You should edit you question to more properly reflect the situation adding your code to show what you're attempting, etc.

Comment: You can consider summing it up and doing a few tests like:

`if $total > 1 GB (1073741824 bytes); then total=$total/1073741824; echo "$total GB"`

`elif MB`

`elif KB`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `du -sh` for getting summarise size in human readable, also you can find the command related help in manual.
Try below command, it will give you the size in Human readable format

```
 du | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024 ; print total "MB" }'

 du | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; print total "GB" }'
```

Comment: thanks for this. It was super helpful for my needs. I made one slight mod to have it round to 2 decimal places in one of my scripts.

`disk_usage="4491780"; echo $(echo $disk_usage | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; printf("%.2fGB\n", total) }')`

   Example:
`user@user-All-Series:~$ disk_usage="4491780"; echo $(echo $disk_usage | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; printf("%.2fGB\n", total) }')
4.28GB
user@user-All-Series:~$`

Picture in action https://imgur.com/a/Us9wjUy

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of @Mahattam response and some others I combined which tallys the total amount in the standard format and then formats the output in human readable.

```
for path in $(awk -F: '{if ($3 >= 1000) print $6}' < /etc/passwd); do disk_usage=0; disk_usage=$(du -s ${path} | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+');  echo "$path: $(echo $disk_usage | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; printf("%.2fGB\n", total) }')"; myAssociativeArray[${path}]=${disk_usage}; done ; total=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${myAssociativeArray[*]}))"); echo "Total disk usage: $(echo $total | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; printf("%.2fGB\n", total) }')"; unset total; unset disk_usage ;
```

[image: Example of how it looks]

How it works.

This could be anything you want to iterate through path list but in this example its just using the /etc/pass to loop over users paths [source is here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199220/how-to-loop-over-users)
`for path in $(awk -F: '{if ($3 >= 1000) print $6}' < /etc/passwd)`

It then calculates the usage per folder and extracts only digits from the output in the loop
`disk_usage=0; disk_usage=$(du -s ${path} | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+')`

It outputs the nice formatting rounded to 2 decimal points
`echo "$path: $(echo $disk_usage | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; printf("%.2fGB\n", total) }')";`

Adds this to the bash associative array
`myAssociativeArray[${path}]=${disk_usage}`

then it sums the total value in the original amount from the array
`total=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${myAssociativeArray[*]}))")`

then we use the same fancy output formatting to show this nicely
`echo "Total disk usage: $(echo $total | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; printf("%.2fGB\n", total) }')";`

I used a variation of this for calculating cPanel Resellers accounts disk usage in the below monster oneliner.

```
Reseller="CPUsernameInputField"; declare -A myAssociativeArray ; echo "==========================================" | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt ; echo "Reseller ${Reseller}'s Disk usage by account"| tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt; for acct in $(sudo grep ${Reseller} /etc/trueuserowners | cut -d: -f1); do disk_usage=0; disk_usage=$(du -s /home/${acct} | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+');  echo "$acct: $(echo $disk_usage | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; printf("%.2fGB\n", total) }')" | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt ; myAssociativeArray[${acct}]=${disk_usage}; done ; total=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${myAssociativeArray[*]}))"); echo "Total disk usage: $(echo $total | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024/1024 ; printf("%.2fGB\n", total) }')" | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt; unset total; unset disk_usage;echo "==========================================" | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt ; echo "Sorted by top users" | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt; for key in "${!myAssociativeArray[@]}"; do printf '%s:%s\n' "$key" "${myAssociativeArray[$key]}"; done | sort -t : -k 2rn | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt;echo "==========================================" | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt ;for key in "${!myAssociativeArray[@]}"; do USER_HOME=$(eval echo ~${key}); echo "Disk breakdown for $key" | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt ; sudo du -h ${USER_HOME} --exclude=/app --exclude=/home/virtfs| grep ^[0-9.]*[G,M]  | sort -rh|head -n20 | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt;echo "=======================================" | tee -a ${Reseller}_disk_breakdown.txt; done
```

[image: Example of the cPanel Reseller disk usage]